# Type parameter in play-json read/write macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros, play-json

I have a parametrized case class `CaseClass[T](name: String, t: T)` for which I would like to have serialization/deserialization using play-json (2.5).

Of course, I cannot have this if I do not have the equivalent for the type `T`, so I define

```
object CaseClass {
  implicit def reads[T: Reads] = Json.reads[CaseClass[T]]
}
```

But I get the following compiler error:

```
overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
   [B](f: B => (String, T))(implicit fu: play.api.libs.functional.ContravariantFunctor[play.api.libs.json.Reads])play.api.libs.json.Reads[B] <and>
   [B](f: (String, T) => B)(implicit fu: play.api.libs.functional.Functor[play.api.libs.json.Reads])play.api.libs.json.Reads[B]
   cannot be applied to ((String, Nothing) => CaseClass[Nothing])
```

If I try to do the same with the `Json.writes` macro, I get the error

```
type mismatch;
   found   : CaseClass[Nothing] => (String, Nothing)
   required: CaseClass[T] => (String, T)
```

What is most surprising, is that neither error occur when I use the `Json.format` macro.

I know I have different solutions to by-pass this problem (using `Json.format`, writing my (de)serializer by hand, ...), but I'm rather curious about why this can occur here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either a limitation in the `Json.reads` macro, type inference, or both. Type inference has a little bit to do with it at least, because you can see that something is being inferred as `Nothing` in the error message.

If you use the compiler flag `-Ymacro-debug-lite`, you can see the macro generated AST.

```
implicit def reads[T](implicit r: Reads[T]): Reads[CaseClass[T]] = 
  Json.reads[CaseClass[T]]
```

Translates to:

```
_root_.play.api.libs.json.JsPath.$bslash("name").read(json.this.Reads.StringReads)
  .and(_root_.play.api.libs.json.JsPath.$bslash("t").read(r))
  .apply((CaseClass.apply: (() => <empty>)))
```

Cleaned up, it looks like:

```
implicit def reads[T](implicit w: Reads[T]): Reads[CaseClass[T]] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").read(Reads.StringReads) and
  (JsPath \ "t" ).read(r)
)(CaseClass.apply _)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't compile because the type parameter of `CaseClass.apply` isn't supplied and is inferred as `Nothing`. Manually adding `T` to `apply` fixes the issue, but the macro likely doesn't know that `T` in `CaseClass[T]` is important.

To address the type inference issue with more detail, with the `Reads` combinators, we're calling `FunctionalBuilder.CanBuild2#apply`, which expects a `(A1, A2) => B`. But the compiler cannot properly infer `A2`.

For `Writes`, there is a similar issue, where we need a `B => (A1, A2)`, but compiler is unable to infer `B` or `A2` correctly (which is `CaseClass[T]` and `T`, respectively).

`Format` requires both of the above functions, and the compiler is able to reason that `A2` must be `T`.

Comment: What I still don't get is why the compiler error says there is an ambiguity on the `FunctionalBuilder.CanBuild2#apply`, between two methods, one of which clearly cannot apply (`Reads` is not a contravariant functor, and the parameter's type is nowhere near `B => (String, Nothing)`), while it is able to choose the right one for `Writes`, although with a problem on type inference that you explained clearly. From what you say. I guess the `Format` case is explained by the fact that type inference is easier on invariant functors, since there are more parameters (the two functions, as you said).